# How to disable s:select dynamically

Tags: javascript, struts2

When I'm trying to disable  dynamically, it's not disabled..

```
document.getElementById('selectId').disabled=true
```

Comment: ca you be more clear what you mean by  dynamically?

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementById('selectId').disabled=true.` should be:
`document.getElementById('selectId').disabled=true;`

---

Some extra info because of the error in my first answer:

The disabled attribute can accept any value.
As long as this attribute is present, the element will be disabled regardless of its value.

```
<input type="text" value="This is disabled" disabled>
<input type="text" value="This is disabled" disabled="disabled">
<input type="text" value="This is disabled" disabled="true">
<input type="text" value="This is disabled" disabled="false">

<input type="text" value="This is not disabled">
```

Although in scripting, it is different.

```
document.formname.elementname.disabled = true; //disabled
document.formname.elementname.disabled = false; //enabled
```

The same is true for these attributes:
checked (radio button and checkbox)
selected (option)
nowrap (td)

Comment: i believe this should be part of comment and not as an answer

Comment: @Umesh Awasthi: I figured out my error (and included this in my answer for my future reference). Hope you like this one better!

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [this documentation](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/docs/select.html) for struts, the "disabled" attribute of a select element is of type "String", I would at least try putting .disable="disabled;" in your code and seeing if that works.

The other solution I've found to a Struts vs. HTML problem was [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/504166/Struts/Showing-Hiding-div-tag-Struts). The solution was to use the attribute `theme='simple'` in the element tag(your  tag or one of it's containers in this case). That let HTML do its functions over Struts trying to do its functions when it comes to display. I suggest this answer because you may be having a behind-the-scenes issue where Struts doesn't like the HTML "disabled" attribute you are trying to use and it doesn't fire properly. So try adding theme='simple' (or some other theme) and see if anything changes.

Comment: that one is with the select tag and it will eventually get translated to the equivalent HTML code.